# What are the difference Between "delete ptr" and RAI Initialization

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++20, raii

I tried this `RAII`: As we can see the `ctor` and `dtor` are working properly. *As this src-code is simple enough.*

```
$PL_STD_MEM::MemDerive derive;
derive.printStack();
derive.printStack(1, 0);
derive.printStack(1);
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> ```
> in namespace std_mem class MemBase constructor:         0
> in namespace std_mem class MemDerive constructor:       1
> in namespace std_mem MemDerive printStack()
> in namespace std_mem MemBase printStack( 1, 0 )
> in namespace std_mem MemBase printStack( true )
> in namespace std_mem class MemDerive destructor:        1
> in namespace std_mem class MemBase destructor:          0
> ```

And I tried this `pointer` to have this `polymorphism`: *Why does the `dtor` of `MemDerive` did not show up/invoke?*

```
$PL_STD_MEM::MemBase* memBaseOfDerive;
{
    memBaseOfDerive = new $PL_STD_MEM::MemDerive();
    memBaseOfDerive->printStack();
    memBaseOfDerive->printStack(1, 0);
    memBaseOfDerive->printStack(true);
    
}
delete memBaseOfDerive;
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> ```
> in namespace std_mem class MemBase constructor:         0
> in namespace std_mem class MemDerive constructor:       1
> in namespace std_mem MemDerive printStack()
> in namespace std_mem MemBase printStack( 1, 0 )
> in namespace std_mem MemBase printStack( true )
> in namespace std_mem class MemBase destructor:          0
> ```

> **Why does the `dtor` of `class MemDerive` did not show up/invoke?**

Comment: I would say that you did not make your destructors virtual.  In that case, when you destroy a `MemBase`, you'll call the `MemBase` destructor.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, Thank you, thank you, thank you sir!,

Comment: Thanks to use of `$` in identifiers (among other things) this code is not standard C++.   If it is some non-standard language based on C++ (e.g. Managed C++?) tagging appropriately will increase chances of getting useful answers.

Comment: @Peter, I'm using this kind of naming-conventions to my project, specially at this namespace-aliasing: `namespace $DN_MODULE_NAME = domain::name::module_name;`

Comment: @Peter, Microsoft's C and C++ compilers have always allowed $ in identifiers, likely because DEC did.  gcc has an option to allow them.

Comment: @TimRoberts   Then the question would be better tagged accordingly (e.g.  visual-c++) to have a better chance of getting useful advice relevant to the OP's situation.

Comment: @Peter - No, it wouldn't.  The `$` in the names is just an interesting distraction, and is totally unrelated to his problem.  His obvious problem was not using a virtual destructor, which is a universal C++ problem.